# Printing a specific element when reading CSV File using python

Tags: python, csv

Assuming I have the below dataset

```
10,"XG16008168",9/12/2017 0:00:00,9/13/2017 0:00:00,2/23/2018 0:00:00,"Whatever","07210","25978","Main","Yes",3/9/2018 0:00:00,,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,,0,,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,,0,,0,,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,,0,
11,"X000000000",11/30/2017 0:00:00,9/25/2017 0:00:00,2/27/2018 0:00:00,"Whatever 004","07210","25978","Main","Yes",3/9/2018 0:00:00,,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,,0,,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,"Missing valve number.",0,,0,,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,,0,
```

I read this CSV file using the following:

```
with open("AccessTable.txt", "r") as RTCData:
    with open("RTCOutput.csv", "w") as RTCOutput:
        ALLRows = csv.reader(RTCData, delimiter=',')

        for row in ALLRows:
            rows.append(row)

            print(row[1][1])
```

I am trying to print an element of the CSV file.

So by printing `row[1][1]` I was expecting `"X000000000"` but instead I get `"1"` which is the second character in `"11"`.

Can you please tell me how to spit out how to extract elements?

Comment: Are you reading the text file or a csv file ?? ```with open("AccessTable.txt", "r") as RTCData:
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I renamed the "AccessTable.txt" to "AccessTable.csv" but still getting the same output

Comment: I am trying to read a txt file generated by an Access database.

Comment: In my understanding you are victim of a typo.  It's `print(rows[1][1])` (note _rows_, not _row_).  Another problem is that your code is seemingly misaligned, the `print(rows[1][1])` shouldn't be outside of the `with` blocks, when all file i/o has been completed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using row[1][1] but it should be row[1].

Try printing row in python shell you will able to analysis thing easily. Example index value of each item, row is a list of items.

```
with open("/home/lavanya/Desktop/AccessTable.txt", "r") as RTCData:

    with open("RTCOutput.csv", "w") as RTCOutput:

        ALLRows = csv.reader(RTCData, delimiter=',')

        for row in ALLRows:

            rows.append(row)
            print row
            print(row[1][1])
```

Comment: @kerlosSaad, As you can see this is a list, You can access these element by there index. pt = ['223', 'QG17001687', '8/31/2017 0:00:00', '9/1/2017 0:00:00', '4/2/2018 0:00:00', 'Qso Construction Department 600', '26509', '33123', 'Main', 'No', '', '', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '', '0', '', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '1', '0', '0', '0', '', '0', '', '0', '', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '0', '', '0', '']. print pt[0]

Comment: row[1] would print the whole row instead I want to print one of the elements of that row.

Comment: No, row[1] will select the second element of the list. Debug your code...

Answer (score 0):

You are displaying `row`, not `rows`, so you are displaying a character from the second element of each row.

Comment: so how to display the whole character not its element? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> import csv
>>> with open('eggs.csv', 'rb') as csvfile:
...     spamreader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=' ', quotechar='|')
...     for row in spamreader:
...         print(', '.join(row))
Spam, Spam, Spam, Spam, Spam, Baked Beans
Spam, Lovely Spam, Wonderful Spam
```

Comment: then how would you print the first  "Spam" only ?

Answer (score 0):

Just a small bit of clean up for your future use as well as your answer.  When you use your `for row in ALLRows:` statement, you are iterating through all of the rows already.  That means `row` now contains:

```
11,"X000000000",11/30/2017 0:00:00,9/25/2017 0:00:00,2/27/2018 0:00:00,"Whatever 004","07210","25978","Main","Yes",3/9/2018 0:00:00,,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,,0,,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,"Missing valve number.",0,,0,,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,,0,
```

If you want to iterate through the individual items of THAT you can then do the below

```
# Put both open statements on a single line.  A bit cleaner, but does the same thing.
with open("AccessTable.txt", "r") as RTCData, open("RTCOutput.csv", "w") as RTCOutput:
    ALLRows = csv.reader(RTCData, delimiter=',')

    # Make a huge array from the CSV file
    rows = [row for row in ALLRows]
    rows.append(row)

    # OR
    for row in ALLRows:
        # Iterate through all of the cells of this row
        for cell in row:
            print(cell)

        # And to access a single item of the row:
        part_number = row[1]
```

Good luck!

Comment: thank you that worked. C++ is my first language. Just started with python. so I appreciate the help!

Comment: WAY easier than c++!  You just lose gobs of performance with python.  I LOVE it, but I don't need gobs of speed most times.